# Merging conflict with Unity Script Assemblies

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to merge my changes to the main repository branch. I accidentally merged all my Unity files on the last merge and I think that caused an error for my next merge . I get the following error:

```
% hg --repository C:\kiln\development merge --verbose --tool=internal:fail 4595
~/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.pidb: untracked file differs
~/Assembly-UnityScript-Editor.pidb: untracked file differs
~/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll: untracked file differs
~/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll.mdb: untracked file differs
~/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-UnityScript-Editor.dll: untracked file differs
~/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-UnityScript-Editor.dll.mdb: untracked file differs
~/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll: untracked file differs
~/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll.mdb: untracked file differs
abort: untracked files in working directory differ from files in requested revision
```

I'm not sure what to do now. I was thinking about deleting those files from my local repository and then pulling from the main repo. However, I'm afraid those files might damage my game somehow.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should not check the `Library` folder into Mercurial. From the Unity Manual:

> When checking the project into a version control system, you should add the Assets and the ProjectSettings directories to the system. The Library directory should be completely ignored - when using external version control, it's only a local cache of imported assets.

(see also http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html)

Specific to your question: All `dll` and `mdb`-files in the `Library/ScriptAssemblies` folder are automatically regenerated from your code files so you can safely delete these files. Unity will regenerate them when it's recompiling the code in your project.